# data breaks on x-axis appear at end of day instead of start

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to put some time series data in a heatmap-like plot. I have made a stripped down example below. I apologize for "large" data blob but I had trouble reproducing it with more artificial examples.

The problem is that in the example the data goes from the 28th to the 30th. But in the plot you would think that there is data from the 27th to the 29th.
The breaks are put at the end of the day instead of at the start which would be natural.

I have tried anything I could think of, setting the breaks manually, but that doesn't change where they are put.

So how can I change it so that the dates displayed are instead the 29th and 30th?

DATA:

```
data <- structure(list(time_run = structure(c(1503968136, 1503938008, 
1503962343, 1503956548, 1503917153, 1504059128, 1504011336, 1504078913, 
1503915993, 1503968136, 1503938008, 1503962343, 1503956548, 1503917153, 
1504059128, 1504011336, 1504078913, 1503915993, 1503968136, 1503938008, 
1503962343, 1503956548, 1503917153, 1504059128, 1504011336, 1504078913, 
1503915993, 1503968136, 1503938008, 1503962343, 1503956548, 1503917153, 
1504059128, 1504011336, 1504078913, 1503915993, 1503968136, 1503938008, 
1503962343, 1503956548, 1503917153, 1504059128, 1504011336, 1504078913, 
1503915993, 1503968136, 1503938008, 1503962343, 1503956548, 1503917153, 
1504059128, 1504011336, 1504078913, 1503915993, 1503968136, 1503938008, 
1503962343, 1503956548, 1503917153, 1504059128, 1504011336, 1504078913, 
1503915993, 1503968136, 1503938008, 1503962343, 1503956548, 1503917153, 
1504059128, 1504011336, 1504078913, 1503915993, 1503968136, 1503938008, 
1503962343, 1503956548, 1503917153, 1504059128, 1504011336, 1504078913, 
1503915993, 1503968136, 1503938008, 1503962343, 1503956548, 1503917153, 
1504059128, 1504011336, 1504078913, 1503915993, 1503968136, 1503938008, 
1503962343, 1503956548, 1503917153, 1504059128, 1504011336, 1504078913, 
1503915993, 1503968136, 1503938008, 1503962343, 1503956548, 1503917153, 
1504059128, 1504011336, 1504078913, 1503915993), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "Europe/Paris"), x_text = c("NMP (17)", "NMP (17)", 
"NMP (17)", "NMP (17)", "NMP (17)", "NMP (17)", "NMP (17)", "NMP (17)", 
"NMP (17)", "TEA (22)", "TEA (22)", "TEA (22)", "TEA (22)", "TEA (22)", 
"TEA (22)", "TEA (22)", "TEA (22)", "TEA (22)", "ACN (23)", "ACN (23)", 
"ACN (23)", "ACN (23)", "ACN (23)", "ACN (23)", "ACN (23)", "ACN (23)", 
"ACN (23)", "Acetonitrile/Dimethylformamide (29)", "Acetonitrile/Dimethylformamide (29)", 
"Acetonitrile/Dimethylformamide (29)", "Acetonitrile/Dimethylformamide (29)", 
"Acetonitrile/Dimethylformamide (29)", "Acetonitrile/Dimethylformamide (29)", 
"Acetonitrile/Dimethylformamide (29)", "Acetonitrile/Dimethylformamide (29)", 
"Acetonitrile/Dimethylformamide (29)", "DMAP (33)", "DMAP (33)", 
"DMAP (33)", "DMAP (33)", "DMAP (33)", "DMAP (33)", "DMAP (33)", 
"DMAP (33)", "DMAP (33)", "DIPEA (36)", "DIPEA (36)", "DIPEA (36)", 
"DIPEA (36)", "DIPEA (36)", "DIPEA (36)", "DIPEA (36)", "DIPEA (36)", 
"DIPEA (36)", "TPA (42)", "TPA (42)", "TPA (42)", "TPA (42)", 
"TPA (42)", "TPA (42)", "TPA (42)", "TPA (42)", "TPA (42)", "ACN (43)", 
"ACN (43)", "ACN (43)", "ACN (43)", "ACN (43)", "ACN (43)", "ACN (43)", 
"ACN (43)", "ACN (43)", "ACN (46)", "ACN (46)", "ACN (46)", "ACN (46)", 
"ACN (46)", "ACN (46)", "ACN (46)", "ACN (46)", "ACN (46)", "Acetonitrile/Methanol (47)", 
"Acetonitrile/Methanol (47)", "Acetonitrile/Methanol (47)", "Acetonitrile/Methanol (47)", 
"Acetonitrile/Methanol (47)", "Acetonitrile/Methanol (47)", "Acetonitrile/Methanol (47)", 
"Acetonitrile/Methanol (47)", "Acetonitrile/Methanol (47)", "Pthalic Anhydride (48)", 
"Pthalic Anhydride (48)", "Pthalic Anhydride (48)", "Pthalic Anhydride (48)", 
"Pthalic Anhydride (48)", "Pthalic Anhydride (48)", "Pthalic Anhydride (48)", 
"Pthalic Anhydride (48)", "Pthalic Anhydride (48)", "ACN (26)", 
"ACN (26)", "ACN (26)", "ACN (26)", "ACN (26)", "ACN (26)", "ACN (26)", 
"ACN (26)", "ACN (26)"), c_ord = c(24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
24L, 24L, 24L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 29L, 
29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 
85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 
27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 
31L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 
50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L), value = c(9837.2490234375, 
9145.20068359375, 8794.9443359375, 8782.52001953125, 10083.5, 
9837.2900390625, 8973.68896484375, 8972.79248046875, 10112.3569335938, 
3006.42431640625, 2483.09973144531, 2297.7724609375, 2388.14697265625, 
3180.48327636719, 2907.27026367188, 2407.63500976562, 2381.24938964844, 
3600.30932617188, 809.412658691406, 790.167205810547, 698.132263183594, 
715.636016845703, 1123.26507568359, 728.464904785156, 653.518646240234, 
581.541839599609, 1139.99267578125, 1109.13757324219, 1007.88500976562, 
960.396789550781, 992.408813476562, 1136.28955078125, 1090.0615234375, 
1000.72674560547, 963.919616699219, 1155.56555175781, 2972.392578125, 
3045.79138183594, 2519.54443359375, 2830.70581054688, 4292.25, 
2794.20654296875, 2464.75134277344, 2213.01623535156, 3474.59985351562, 
6243.59130859375, 5039.56372070312, 4662.6640625, 4833.80029296875, 
6457.42724609375, 6183.39208984375, 5053.65649414062, 4982.33056640625, 
7820.1474609375, 569.280151367188, 525.962310791016, NA, NA, 
568.004791259766, 568.837036132812, 526.013427734375, 529.354675292969, 
601.071899414062, 6509.4921875, 5798.27709960938, 5015.94189453125, 
5225.66235351562, 8109.38256835938, 5580.72314453125, 4410.88842773438, 
3981.27697753906, 8123.06518554688, 3046.7998046875, 2847.50915527344, 
2434.40698242188, 2575.9501953125, 3872.27795410156, 2554.265625, 
2210.39123535156, 2017.80932617188, 3846.21325683594, 720.536865234375, 
744.396423339844, 743.815673828125, 683.698913574219, 800.720550537109, 
693.875, 719.847290039062, 708.015197753906, 767.747467041016, 
10337.0947265625, 9417.3125, 9031.552734375, 9194.966796875, 
10259.4594726562, 10270.6875, 9491.2001953125, 9433.85546875, 
10691.4228515625, NA, NA, NA, NA, 551.797607421875, NA, NA, NA, 
547.68701171875)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-108L), .Names = c("time_run", "x_text", "c_ord", "value"))
```

CODE:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)


    p <- ggplot(data=data, aes(x=time_run, y = reorder(x_text, c_ord), fill=log10(value))) + 
         geom_tile() +
         scale_x_datetime(labels = date_format("%Y-%m-%d"), breaks=date_breaks("day")) +
         theme_classic() +
         theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=30, hjust = 1)) +
         theme(panel.background=element_rect(fill="lightgrey", colour="lightgrey"))


      p
```

[image]

```
sort(unique(data$time_run))

[1] "2017-08-28 12:26:33 CEST" "2017-08-28 12:45:53 CEST" "2017-08-28 18:33:28 CEST" "2017-08-28 23:42:28 CEST" "2017-08-29 01:19:03 CEST"
[6] "2017-08-29 02:55:36 CEST" "2017-08-29 14:55:36 CEST" "2017-08-30 04:12:08 CEST" "2017-08-30 09:41:53 CEST"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be caused by the use of timezones in date_format(). You can write your own format function that it does not include any timezone information.

```
my_date_format <- function (format = "%Y-%m-%d") {
    function(x) format(x, format)
}

p <- ggplot(data=data, aes(x=time_run, y = reorder(x_text, c_ord), fill=log10(value))) + 
    geom_tile() +
    scale_x_datetime(labels = my_date_format("%Y-%m-%d"), breaks=date_breaks("day")) +
    theme_classic() +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=30, hjust = 1)) +
    theme(panel.background=element_rect(fill="lightgrey", colour="lightgrey"))


p
```

Comment: Thanks! Based on that hint I found that you can also use `lubridate` to do `labels = date_format("%Y-%m-%d", tz = tz(data$time_run))`. It looks like actual placement on the plot is not affected by the timezone though.